# WIX: Installing a service - AppId entries ignored/too late?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, dcom

I have been attempting to create an installer using WIX (3.10.1.2213).

I am installing a Windows Service that uses DCOM.

I have a component that uses **ServiceInstall** and **ServiceControl** to do what I require.

However I am having issues when it comes to the **AppId** entries.
If I use the following...

```
<AppId Id="{REALGUID}" Advertise="no" Description="MyDescription" LocalService="MyService" ServiceParameters="-Service" />
```

...My installation fails when attempting to start the service - with the ever helpful ***"...failed to start.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services".***

However, if I add the registry entries manually - outside of WIX (even by exporting the entries that WIX creates - so they are definitely the same) - the installation succeeds.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?
In summary, WIX creates the entries I expect, but installation fails.
If I export these entries and start from scratch, merge the entries into the registry and rerun the installer, it succeeds.

I have attempted to move the AppId entry to other locations in the wxs file.  I have also attempted to manually set the registry entries using `<RegistryValue...>`, but it appears to have the same result (I see the entries get created, but the service fails to start).

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but this service requires another entry under `HKCR\AppID\{GUID}` which I do create using `<RegistryValue...>`.  I'm not sure if that is somehow causing a conflict and I can't currently debug the service as it doesn't get far enough.

Also, from [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/appid.html), I see...

> If this element is nested under a Fragment, Module, or Product
>   element, it must be advertised.

But I don't fully understand it.  Does it mean if 'directly' nested under...?
Or could this be my problem and my wxs file could be ordered badly, because I need registry entries instead of being Advertised?

It is currently something like this...

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory...>
    <Component...>
      <File...>
      <AppId...>
      <RegistryValue...>
      <ServiceInstall...>
      <ServiceControl...>
```

I am very confused - but hopefully missing something obvious.
Hopefully someone can shed some light on it for me.

Regards,
Ads.

If it helps, here is an edited extract of the component in question...

```
    <Component Id="ServiceControl" Guid='REALGUID' >
      <File Id="MyApplication.exe" Name="MyApplication.exe" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetDir)\MyApplication.exe" />
      <AppId Id="{REALGUID}" Advertise="no" Description="MyApplication" LocalService="MyApplication" ServiceParameters="-Service" />
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="AppID\{REALGUID}" Name="Group" Value="[GROUP]" Type="string" Action="write" />
      <ServiceInstall
                        Id="ServiceInstaller"
                        Type="ownProcess"
                        Name="MyApplication"
                        DisplayName="My Application"
                        Description="Some Description"
                        Start="auto"
                        Account="LocalSystem"
                        Interactive="yes"
                        ErrorControl="normal"
                        Vital="yes" >
        <ServiceDependency Id="[FTPSERVICE]" />
      </ServiceInstall>
      <ServiceControl Id="MyApplication" Name="MyApplication" Start="install" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
    </Component>
```